# Исключение InvalidOperaionException при работе с ComboBox (C# WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms

В моей программе на форме присутствуют три элемента ComboBox. Я хочу передать значения из них в код:

```
string vhost = VirtualHostPick.GetItemText(VirtualHostPick.SelectedItem);
string exchange_name = ExchangePicker.GetItemText(ExchangePicker.SelectedItem);
string routingKey = RoutingKeyPicker.GetItemText(RoutingKeyPicker.SelectedItem);
```

Но во время работы программы возникает исключение **InvalidOperationException**:

> System.InvalidOperationException: "Недопустимая операция в нескольких потоках: попытка доступа к элементу управления 'VirtualHostPick' не из того потока, в котором он был создан."

Я пробовал решить проблему через отдельный метод с Invoke, но не смог придумать, как возвращать string, а не void:

```
private void VhostPicker(object selectedItem) 
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
        Invoke((Action<object>)VhostPicker, selectedItem);
    else
        VirtualHostPick.GetItemText(selectedItem);
}
```

Comment: Юзайте Dispatcher, он работает в том потоке в котором находится UI, соответственно код вызванный через диспатчер будет вызван в одном потоке с UI

Comment: @Aarnihauta Dispatcher - это WPF

Comment: @aepot он если не изменяет память тоже работает на винформах

Comment: @Aarnihauta изменяет, в винформах используют `Control.Invoke()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для .NET 6 и новее - [Invoke<T>(Func<T>)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#system-windows-forms-control-invoke-1(system-func((-0))))

```
private string VhostPicker(object selectedItem) 
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
        return Invoke(() => VhostPicker(selectedItem));
    else
        return VirtualHostPick.GetItemText(selectedItem);
}
```

Или для старых версий WinForms

```
private string VhostPicker(object selectedItem) 
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        string result = null;
        Invoke((Action)(() => result = VhostPicker(selectedItem)));
        return result;
    }
    else
        return VirtualHostPick.GetItemText(selectedItem);
}
```

---

Чтобы не схватывать исключение с `VirtualHostPick.SelectedItem`, можно сделать более универсальный метод.

```
private T InvokeFunction<T>(Func<T> func) 
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
        return Invoke(func);
    else
        return func();
}
```

Для старых форм

```
private T InvokeFunction<T>(Func<T> func) 
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        T result = default(T);
        Invoke((Action)(() => result = func()));
        return result;
    }
    else
        return func();
}
```

И вызывать вот так

```
string vhost = InvokeFunction(() => VirtualHostPick.GetItemText(VirtualHostPick.SelectedItem));
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь, но это решение (оба варианта) у меня не работает: выдает ту же ошибку.

Comment: @witchgen быть может оно выдает в каком-то другом месте ошибку. Это решение не может не работать. Вы же в классе окна этот метод размещаете, верно?

Comment: @witchgen а, я понял, вы же к `VirtualHostPick.SelectedItem` обращаетесь вне метода, а значит в сторонне потоке, оттуда и исключение, ща подумаю, как это полечить.

Comment: @witchgen дополнил ответ.

Comment: @witchgen если ответ был полезен, вы можете принять его, поставив зеленую галочку слева от ответа.

Comment: Да, ответ очень помог, большое спасибо! Теперь код работает. Вчера просто не было возможности протестировать Ваше решение.